# How to deal with 'paid help' questions?

Tags: discussion

This one just appeared: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37780/paid-help-for-recovering-deleted-files-after-server-reinstall , where the asker proposes to pay for help

This has been already discussed in the Meta Stack Overflow and seems that the consensus is that this is not allowed, e.g.

[Offering actual money as a bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty) 
[Pay money to SO for quick support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57850/pay-money-to-so-for-quick-support)

How to behave in this situation?

Comment: Just to make sure, you can treat Meta Stack Overflow as Global-Meta, because at the moment it is. Whenever you find a consensus there, you can be sure that it went at least through the hands of one developer.

Comment: @Bobby I thought so but was unsure.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Flag them for moderator attention. The Stack Overflow consensus is applicable here as well, and these should be closed promptly.